# react, typescript - how to set state properties with different types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do I set state using type annotations when my state properties have different types? For example here I would want to write two methods - one to set strings and one to set numbers:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

interface State {
  a: string
  b: string
  c: number
  d: number
}

class TestComponent extends Component<any, State> {
  state:State = {
    a: 'test',
    b: 'test',
    c: 1,
    d: 1
  }

  setStringProperty = (key:keyof State, value:string) => {
    this.setState({
      [key]:value
    })
  }


  render () {
    return <div>test</div>
  }
}

export default TestComponent
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error:(19, 19) TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is
>   not assignable to parameter of type 'State | ((prevState:
>   Readonly, props: Readonly) => State | Pick | null) | Pick | null'.
>   Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties
>   from type 'Pick': a, b, c, d

While this makes sense I do not see how I could write a general method for setting different state properties (either of the same type or different types)?

Comment: @Rafael yes - the problem is that I do not know how to annotate the key argument to set state correctly. Trying someting like `type stringKey = 'a' | 'b'` produces the same error.

Comment: I ended up hacking it with `const obj: any = { [key]: value };this.setState(obj);`.

Comment: Why do you need to write your own `set` method? TypeScript will already type-check `this.setState` against the shape of `state` you've provided to your component. This seems like an over-complication.

Comment: @ethane this is a simple example for my use case - I'm writing my own `setStringProperty` to pass it as a prop.

Comment: I don't know about passing functions that explicity `setState` down as a prop. Firstly, it's convoluted and not straightforward to reason about. Which `this` is used in the child component?

Comment: @ethane I thought it was a pretty common practice...Any way I think this is out of scope for this question?

Comment: Maybe it is, but 'unseen' gotchas like these may likely block you from receiving proper answers.

Comment: Ok, then how would you set state from a nested component? Also maybe the question was not really clear - I want to avoid writing four `setState` functions for four different keys, and have a method for keys of the same type that takes the key name and the value instead.